# pymysql error (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))") is thrown once every two weeks

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have been tearing my hair out over this issue I've had for the past two months: a server in the work office has been reading from Power Meters about once a second, and has been using the following script to make calls inserting into the database. The queries used are are below also. I can run this for two weeks without an issue, then I will suddenly receive the error: "(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")". I have no idea why this error is thrown, nor can I replicate it. Is there something wrong I am doing in my scripting below, or is there a simple way to get around it? Currently I've put a try/except and logging around usages of the database cursor, and it will recreate the db cursor instance and try again, however it's not the ideal solution.

```
from pathlib import Path
import configparser
import logging
from typing import Optional

from pymysql.cursors import Cursor
from pymysql import Connection, connect, OperationalError

class DatabaseAccessLayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db: Optional[Connection] = None
        self.cursor: Optional[Cursor] = None
        self._logger = logging.Logger("DatabaseAccessLayer")
        self._create_database_connection()

    def _create_database_connection(self):
        path = Path.cwd()
        _config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        _config.read(path / 'database_connector' / 'db.ini')
        _host = _config['mysql']['host']
        _user = _config['mysql']['user']
        _password = _config['mysql']['password']
        _database = _config['mysql']['database']
        try:
            self.db = connect(_host, _user, _password, _database)
        except OperationalError as err:
            self._logger.error(f"Error connecting to database: {err}")
        self.db.autocommit(True)
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def get_instance(self):
        return self

    def query(self, sql, data):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, data)
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def query_without_data(self, sql):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            return self.cursor.fetchone()
        except OperationalError as e:
            self._logger.warning(f"Database connection not accessible. Recreating")
            self._create_database_connection()
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def execute(self, sql, data):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql, data)
        except OperationalError as e:
            self._logger.warning(f"Database connection not accessible. Recreating")
            self._create_database_connection()
            self.cursor.execute(sql, data)

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.db.close()
```

```
    def update_power_meter_all(self, identifier: int, power_meter_measurands: PowerMeterMeasurands):

        _update_power_meter_all = (
            'INSERT INTO distributionBoardPowerMeters (currentL1, currentL2, currentL3, powerL1, powerL2, powerL3, '
            'voltageL1, voltageL2, voltageL3, energyTotal, identifier) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, '
            '%s, %s);')
        _data_power_meter_all = (power_meter_measurands.currentL1, power_meter_measurands.currentL2,
                                 power_meter_measurands.currentL3, power_meter_measurands.powerL1,
                                 power_meter_measurands.powerL2, power_meter_measurands.powerL3,
                                 power_meter_measurands.voltageL1, power_meter_measurands.voltageL2,
                                 power_meter_measurands.voltageL3, power_meter_measurands.energyTotal,
                                 identifier)
        self._db.execute(_update_power_meter_all, _data_power_meter_all)
        self.logger.debug(f'Updated into distribution board power meter.')
        self.logger.debug(f"currentL1:{power_meter_measurands.currentL1}, currentL2:{power_meter_measurands.currentL2},"
                          f"currentL3:{power_meter_measurands.currentL3}, powerL1: {power_meter_measurands.powerL2},"
                          f"powerL2:{power_meter_measurands.currentL2}, powerL3: {power_meter_measurands.powerL3}, "
                          f"voltageL1:{power_meter_measurands.voltageL1}, voltageL2:{power_meter_measurands.voltageL2}"
                          f"voltageL3:{power_meter_measurands.voltageL3}, "
                          f"energyTotal: {power_meter_measurands.energyTotal}, identifier: {identifier}")

        _delete_old_entries = 'DELETE FROM distributionBoardPowerMeters WHERE identifier = %s AND createdAt < ' \
                              'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -%s DAY);' % (identifier, DELETE_ROWS_OLDER_THAN_N_DAYS)
        _row_exists = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT identifier FROM distributionBoardPowerMeters WHERE identifier IN (1,2,3));'

        self._db.query_without_data(_delete_old_entries)
        self.logger.debug(f'Removed old DistributionBoardPowerMeter Entries')
```

Comment: Sounds like idle connections are becoming stale, getting closed, and then very infrequently you use these connections from your pool(?) and they're dead.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the connections that are failing are the connections that I know are being used at least once every three seconds, so I feel like it might be something else. Nonetheless I will test for it and see what results

Comment: I am receiving this error as well. I suspect that my strings are too long and it messes up the server. But this is just a guess. Did you made any progress?